# How to enable GOST ciphers in Java client

Tags: java, ssl, network-security, gost3410, gost28147

I want to make an SSL connection to some web servers using Java client while using GOST ciphers in my client cipher list. I tried to check the enabled and supported ciphersuites in Java using: `getEnabledCipherSuites()` and `getSupportedCipherSuites()` and none has returned GOST ciphers. How can I make SSL connection from my Java client to a web server using GOST ciphers? Is there any way to specify my client's list of ciphers to include GOST ciphers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try BouncyCastle SSL library, they support GOST ciphers as far as I remember.